# Android JAVA Byte Code missing after update Gradle and Build Tools

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm using Jacoco to create a coverage report and that was working fine until update Gradle and BuildTools version. Then I revert those changes and work again.

Jacoco looks for **.class** files in here:

> ${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug

This is *app/build/intermediates/classes/debug*. But I've notice that after the upgrade that path is missing, there's no *classes* dir inside *intermediates*

My configuration which is working:

**Project Level Module**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
```

**App Level Module**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

And when updated is this one:

**Project Level Module**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
```

**App Level Module**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
```

I could not find any reference about that path being moved or what could be going on

#### EDIT

My problem is that as the Java Byte Code (generated .class files) does not exists, then Jacoco can not create a coverage report

Comment: Anyone? Is anybody else experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are under `intermediates\javac\debug\compileDebugJavaWithJavac\classes`

You can configure Jacoco to change the classes path.

I'm not familiar with Jacoco but I think it has a property named `includes` which is used for .class files.

Or there should be a `.properties` for it I guess.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why where they moved? and also, is it there any documentation about it?

Comment: @sebasira I couldn't find any documentations, but my guess is it's for cleanup and organized directories for future development. since android is going to end and be replaced with Fuchsia and the Flutter framework will be used with Dart instead of Java, I guess they are preparing the environment for that.

Answer (score 6):

One can change the `classDirectories` used by the coverage task alike this:

```
task "${testTaskName}Coverage" (type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
    ...
    classDirectories = fileTree(
        dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes/${sourcePath}",
        excludes: [ ... ]
    )
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Although your answer is also correct I'm force to mark @MDP as the correct one because he answered earlier.

Comment: @sebasira the other answer does not provide any solution how to change the path. while your "question" does not even contain any actual question - which would be required to tell which answer is the correct one. a sooner answer does not imply a better answer. IDE function `search` > `in path` for pattern `*.class` would have provided just the same information.

Comment: basically, it is "unclear what you are asking" (which commonly is a good reason to put a question on hold), when asking "Is anybody else experiencing the same issue?" - which could mean both of a) "where are the .class files are located?" and b) "how to change the path, so that JaCoCo would find the .class files?" ...therefore the two answers, which answer whole different questions.